# mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage -f pom.xml failes with Package not Found

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, maven

So i have a project with four modules and a parent module.

The structure is:

- contactlist

  - contactlist-controller
  - contactlist-domain
  - contactlist-persistence

mvn clean install works like a charm.

mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage -f ./pom.xml fails with following errors:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Documents/01_Studium/07_Semester/04_SWA/graded-exercise-User/contactlist/contactlist-persistence/src/main/java/persistence/ContactRepository.java:[4,14] package domain does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Documents/01_Studium/07_Semester/04_SWA/graded-exercise-User/contactlist/contactlist-persistence/src/main/java/persistence/ContactRepository.java:[7,60] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Contact
[INFO] 2 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for contactlist 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] contactlist ........................................ SUCCESS [  1.694 s]
[INFO] domain ............................................. SUCCESS [  3.162 s]
[INFO] persistence ........................................ FAILURE [  0.632 s]
[INFO] contactlist-controller ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.659 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-08T11:00:29+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project persistence: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Documents/01_Studium/07_Semester/04_SWA/graded-exercise-User/contactlist/contactlist-persistence/src/main/java/persistence/ContactRepository.java:[4,14] package domain does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/User/Documents/01_Studium/07_Semester/04_SWA/graded-exercise-User/contactlist/contactlist-persistence/src/main/java/persistence/ContactRepository.java:[7,60] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class Contact
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :persistence
```

I pasted the POM Files of each Module. Can anybody help me why this doesn't work?

#### Parent POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.fhnw.swa</groupId>
    <artifactId>contactlist</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>contactlist</name>
    <description>graded exam for swa</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.fhnw.swa.contactlist.ContactlistApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>contactlist-domain</module>
        <module>contactlist-persistence</module>
        <module>contactlist-controller</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.04</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

#### contactlist-controller POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>contactlist</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fhnw.swa</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fhnw.swa.controller</groupId>
    <artifactId>contactlist-controller</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fhnw.swa.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fhnw.swa.domain</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

#### contactlist-domain POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>contactlist</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fhnw.swa</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fhnw.swa.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

#### contactlist-persistence POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>contactlist</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.fhnw.swa</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>com.fhnw.swa.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fhnw.swa.domain</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: the error indicates that something is wrong with your imports in `ContactRepository`. It could also be the case that you need to run a `mvn install` in your domain project, because only then maven will put the domain package in your local repository and will then be able to resolve the dependency when compiling persitence

Comment: @AmirSchnell i deleted the imports and let them create newly by intelliJ didn't work. Thanks though for your help :)